# Axios to get data from database

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, axios

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          data: [],
         };
  }
 updateSearch = (e) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/searchapiKey{1234}&query=${this.state.data}&number=100`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data });
      });
  };
   render()
      return(
            <SearchBar  
               placeholder="Search Food..."
               onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
               value={data}
             />
            <List style={{ paddingTop: hp("2%") }}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                {data.parsed.map(({ type }) => (
                  <Text>{this.state.type.products.title}</Text>
                ))}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </List>
```

Hi, I'm trying to get data from the Spoonacular database using `axios`, I'm trying to search the food with the `SearchBar` and display the content in the `List`, I'm new to programming and I'm not very sure of what I'm doing, when I run the code it tells me `undefined is not an object (evaultaing 'data.parsed.map')`, also it this the right way to use `SearchBar` to get data.

Link to the documentation: https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Search-Grocery-Products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just miss this.state.data

```js
             <TouchableOpacity>
                {this.state.data.map(({ type }) => (
                  <Text>{this.state.type.products.title}</Text>
                ))}
              </TouchableOpacity>
```